# How do you install reveal.js so that jupyter and nbpresent can use it?

Tags: jupyter, reveal.js

I'm experienced with IPython Notebook but just upgraded to Jupyter 4 with nbpresent, and I want to use reveal.js for slideshows.

How can I incorporate reveal.js into my notebook slideshow?

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/damianavila/RISE

Comment: yeah i ended up using RISE instead. simpler and it works the way i expected.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is using nbconvert:

```
jupyter nbconvert presentation.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

For more information, see [nbconvert documentation](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-revealjs).

You would only use RISE if you need to execute commands on the kernel *during* the presentation.